# Azure Functions - Set MediaTypeFormatter for response message?

Tags: azure-functions, mediatypeformatter

I am trying to set a media type formatter for the response of an Azure Function to return an Excel file. I do not want an External File Binding since I want to stream the output to the browser for download, not write the file to a blob or a google sheet or something. I have used the EPPlus library and WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx for this purpose before in other contexts (e.g. WebApi). I was able to import the packages and reference them in my function, but I have not been able to successfully add the formatter and apply it to the response.

Is it possible to get a reference to the HttpConfiguration object for a function to add the formatter? I have tried adding the XlsxMediaTypeFormatter to the CreateResponse call but for some reason it cannot be cast to a MediaTypeFormatter. If I just try to set the MIME type, it says there is no formatter available.

Here's my test function:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx;
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{

    var testData = new List<TestItemDto>
    {
        new TestItemDto
        {
            Id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
            Name = "Test Item 1" 
        }, 
        new TestItemDto
        {
            Id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
            Name = "Test Item 2" 
        }
    };

    //var excelMediaType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    var formatter = new XlsxMediaTypeFormatter(headerHeight: 25f, freezeHeader: true);

    var response = req.CreateResponse<List<TestItemDto>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, testData, (MediaTypeFormatter)formatter);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "TestData.xlsx"
    };
    return response;
}

public class TestItemDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I get the error:

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx.XlsxMediaTypeFormatter' to 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter'
```

My project.json file:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "EPPlus": "3.1.3.3", 
        "WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx" : "1.0.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like assembly version mismatch, but I can't see where yet. Can you try to run the same code locally with `csproj` precompiled function? Seems to work for me...

Comment: I tried it locally and got runtime errors (null reference) instantiating the XlsxMediaTypeFormatter. Clearly that library won't work in a function (it was designed for use in a WebApi). Still looking for other solutions for setting the media type and returning a file to the browser from a function. I guess I'll try using the EPPlus library to generate the file, and then stream it directly into the response content?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best answer, since it bypasses the MediaTypeFormatter and just creates the response content directly. However, I was able to get it to work by ditching the XlsxMediaTypeFormatter, creating the excel workbook directly with the EPPlus library, and streaming it to the browser (using the same DTO and test collection as above):

```
// try to create an excel file by hand with EPPlus
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
var wsTest = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestSheet");
//Load the collection starting from cell A1...
wsTest.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(testData, true);
wsTest.Cells[wsTest.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

var excelMediaType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(pck.GetAsByteArray()));
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(excelMediaType);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
      FileName = "TestData.xlsx"
};
return response;
```

I will leave the question open in case someone can answer the actual question (e.g. how to use a MediaTypeFormatter).